# Обновление данных Gridview

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, gridview

Не получается обновить данные в GridView,по нажатию кнопки Изменить, появляются текстовые поля, изменяю данные ,затем нажимаю обновить -появляются старые данные. В методе rowupdating получаю данные из textbox'ов, они почему то без изменений.

```
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {   TextBox title1 = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("textBox1"));
        TextBox title2 = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("textBox2"));
        TextBox title3 = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("textBox3"));
        TextBox title4 = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("textBox7"));
        TextBox title5 = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("textBox8"));

        bool f = WS.UpdateDate(Convert.ToInt32(title1.Text), title3.Text, title2.Text, title4.Text, title5.Text);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь данные ещё не обновились в TextBox'ах, так как событие [RowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) создано для проверки и возможной отмены действия обновления.

Обратите внимание на параметры события (представлены типом [GridViewUpdateEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx))
У параметров есть свойства OldValues и NewValues.

Comment: e.NewValues.Count = 0. почему так....